# Clear data in Android firmware below 4.1 not removing any data

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, clear-cache, android-4.1-jelly-bean

My apps runs for Android 4.0.3 and above version.
I have a problem on firmware below 4.1 on **Clear Data from phone setting**.

On Android version 4.1 and above (*this is the correct one*), when I clear data my app via phone setting it also clear/delete the folder in `..android/data/com....myApp/`

But on Android below 4.1, lets say 4.0.4, when I clear data from phone setting it doesn't remove the folder, thus there are no effect or simply the clear data is not properly working.

What I need is that when I Clear Data from Phone Setting it also remove the folder from `//android/data/com....myApp`.

Does anyone know whether this is expected condition from Android below 4.1? Are there any documentation on any portal for it?